# C - Assigning a char* to a char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a function that has an argument 'char *argument', like:

```
function(char *x) { ... }
```

When I call this function, I pass a char array as the argument

```
function(char_array);
```

In the function, I want to iterate the elements of the array char by char, so my thought was creating an array in the function and to it assign the argument of the function (i.e., char *x) so I'm able to iterate the elements of the array one by one, however, I don't seem to be able to do this assignment and I get an error that says:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[8000]’ from type ‘char *’
```

So the question is: How do I assign a char pointer to a char array?

Comment: How are you declaring this "char_array" and exactly how do you use it in the call?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I want to *iterate* the elements ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But what you can do is iterate `x` directly as pointers can be used like arrays just as arrays can be converted to pointers. E.g.

```
function(char *x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 And if the size of the array is not stored in some constant, you need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was complicating as I didn't know you could iterate the pointer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't unless you manually copy the memory from the pointer (and somehow either store the size of the memory into another parameter or get it from another source).

To retain information on the `sizeof()` of the array, pass it by reference:

```
void function( const char (&arr)[8000] )
```

Alternatively you can just use the pointer to access the data (also if the array name decays into a pointer)

```
void function(char* arr) {
    printf("%c", arr[2]);
}
```

make sure to respect the array boundaries in that case.